# How to create new img in new div in new header in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create slider in js. Here is my code. The problem is how I've mentioned, with creating new `img` element in new `div` element in new `header` element "in the same time", sth. like `header > div > img`.

```
const myRequest = new Request('./database.json');
const myHeader = document.querySelector('main');

export const headerTwo = (fragment) => {
    fetch(myRequest)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.warn(response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function () {

    let header = document.createElement('div');

    // above is the problem with creating header > div > img 

    header.setAttribute('class', 'slider');

    const slideList = [{
        img: "https://",
        text: 'sth 1'},{
        img: "https://",
        text: 'sth 2'},{
        img: "https://",
        text: 'sth 3'}
        ];

    const time = 3000;
    let active = 0;

    const changeSlide = () => {
        active++;
        if (active === slideList.length) {
            active = 0;
        }
        header.src = slideList[active].img;
        header.textContent = slideList[active].text;
        };
    let indexInterval = setInterval(changeSlide, time);

    myHeader.appendChild(header);
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Co to ????');
    })
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('--------- ', error);
});


}
```

Comment: You can't set an `src` property on a `div` tag - it won't do anything. It looks like you're expecting that to magically create and append an image from it.

Comment: I think that jQuery can help. I used it in this way: $('.slider').wrapAll('<header><div></div></header>');

Comment: I know that jQuery is a bit passe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That code should do it

```
let header = document.createElement('header')
let div = document.createElement('div')
let img = document.createElement('img')
img.setAttribute('src','') // set value
div.appendChild(img)
header.appendChild(div)
```

Then append header wherever you need it